# Perl Linux::Inotify2 - can't respond to events anymore

Tags: perl, events, inotify

I am getting some really weird behavior when using [Linux::Inotify2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Linux-Inotify2/) module for watching a directory for any newly created files.

I had made a test script to see how it worked, and once that was done, I went on to incorporating its usage in the other scripts, in which it didn't work. Then, when I tried my earlier test script again to find some information, strangely that stopped working as well. It hasn't worked since then. There were no package/distro upgrades during that time.

The problem is that it has stopped responding to events. Here's the test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Linux::Inotify2;

my $inotify = new Linux::Inotify2 or die "unable to create new inotify object: $!";

my $dir = "/my/dir";

$inotify->watch($dir, IN_CREATE, sub {
    my $e = shift;
    print $e->fullname;
}) or die " Can't watch $!";

1 while $inotify->poll;
```

A strace on the running script kills the script. Otherwise when strace is used when starting the script, then it does seem to read the new events, but there's no response to those events. Any suggestions for debugging this further ?

Answer (score 2):

I had forgotten to set the $|.